# Functional way of finding if string contains substring?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, iteration, tail-recursion

I am new to Haskell and Functional programming and wondering how nested loops can be implemented using functional recursive iteration. In particular, I want to write a function that will return True or False depending on whether a substring is present in a string.

Note: There must be a function in the standard library to do this but, because I am trying to learn functional programming, I want to implement such a function myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by writing a function which computes all the suffixes:

```
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes [1,2,3] = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []]
```

This can be implemented by recursion. In the libraries, this is called `tails`.

Then, you can write a function to check whether a string is a prefix of another string

```
isPrefix :: String -> String -> Bool
isPrefix "a" "abc" = True
isPrefix "bc" "abc" = False
```

Again, recursion suffices.

Finally, exploit both functions to check whether a given string is a prefix of some suffix of another given string.

(This is not as efficient as [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), but it's simple to code.)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just one thing, the function is actually `tail` not `tails`.

Comment: `tails`, from `Data.List`, is correct. `tails [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []]`.